# Execute only one function using self-invoking function in a for loop and exit

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, closures, self-invoking-function

I want to implement a clicker by a user and by a computer randomly . I need to stop user click event after one cell is clicked .My random function is not executing .It is because left self-invoking functions are waiting to be clicked.You need to click only one cell(id) and continue executing random function .

```
for(var i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
   (function (index){
     if(!once) {
       $(temp[index]).click(function(e){
         if($(temp[index]).text()=="" && !once && turns%2==0){
            $(temp[index]).text(player1Val);
            console.log("first player clicked ");
            once = true;
            turns++;
            return;
         }
       });
     } //if
     else {
       console.log("break out ");
       return false;
     }
   })(i);
 }
 function generateRandom(){
    var temp = [];
    cnt++;
    for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
      if($(ids[i]).text()==""){
        temp.push(ids[i]);
      }
    }
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*temp.length);
    if(temp.length>0 && turns%2==1){
      $(temp[id]).text(player2Val);
      turns++;
     }
     return id;
```

}

Comment: What is your question. This is very unclear and will be closed if not clarified.

Comment: Perhaps  `$(temp[Math.floor(Math.random()*temp.length)]).one("click",function(e){` or `$(temp[Math.floor(Math.random()*temp.length)]).trigger("click")`

Comment: No i meant self invoking function inside a for loop .

Comment: Your edit did not clarify the actual problem you are trying to resolve.

Comment: I need to run click event once and continue with a random clicker function and run it on turn.

Comment: One click per button, or one click for all of them? Use `.one()` if you want it per-button. If you want it just once for everything, either check the `once` variable inside the function, or use `.off()` to remove all the handlers when the handler is first run.

Comment: I need one click for all of them . I think .off() is what i need but i cannot use it .Nothing changes .

Comment: I need to know  how to break out of the for loop and self invoked functions after one cell have been clicked .